# GluonMobile + Jackson = java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.function.ToLongFunction

Tags: jackson, gluon-mobile

I'm porting a desktop JavaFx Application that requires Jackson to GluonMobile, it's my first time using this platform and I end up on the next stacktrace with a NoClassDefFoundError.

I would like to know if this requires a feature not supported by GluonMobile or if I just forgot to include something properly.

```
Apr 19, 2018 8:25:02 PM com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7Support <clinit>
WARNING: Unable to load JDK7 types (annotations, java.nio.file.Path): no Java7 support added
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'javax.servlet.Servlet'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>javax.servlet.Servlet</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
TRACE Task Catching
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.function.ToLongFunction
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findClassInClasspathForLoader(Native Method)
at java.lang.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:193)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:515)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:475)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.InstantSerializer.<init>(InstantSerializer.java:38)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.InstantSerializer.<clinit>(InstantSerializer.java:35)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule.<init>(JavaTimeModule.java:161)
at com.general.plugin.jackson.json.JacksonObjectMapper.<clinit>(JacksonObjectMapper.java:214)
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:218)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:176)
at com.general.core.startup.Configuration.getSharableInstance(Configuration.java:69)
at com.general.core.startup.AbstractClient.<init>(AbstractClient.java:39)
at com.objectdb.core.startup.Client.<init>(Client.java:31)
at com.objectdb.ui.service.ClientFactory.getDBClient(ClientFactory.java:39)
at com.objectdb.ui.service.ClientTask.getDBClient(ClientTask.java:13)
at com.objectdb.ui.startup.Main$2.call(Main.java:30)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:837)
```

Comment: The error is related to Java 8 API (`java.util.function.ToLongFunction`), that is not supported on mobile using the jfxmobile plugin 1.3.10, as it requires Java 7 and some Java 8 features (like lambdas). If you want to use Java 8/9 features consider using [Gluon VM](http://gluonhq.com/statuspage-gluon-vm/) (still under developer preview though).

Comment: Thanks for your support Jose, greatly appreciated. Sadly I'm using controlsfx, controlsfx 8 seems to work with jfxmobile 1 but controlsfx 8/9 seem to give different compilation errors in jfxmobile 2. I will continue testing and see if I can also adapt the project to make it more mobile friendly. I don't mind to drop lambdas, they are syntactic sugar anyway but needing to drop jackson would be a bummer. I suppose the issue appears when using jackson-module-parameter-names and jackson-datatype-jsr310 but maybe I can replace those.

Comment: Did you test Jackson on Gluon VM? Maybe you couldn't because ControlsFX compilation errors? Also, are you targeting Android or iOS or both?

Comment: I couldn't test on GluonVM because of ControlsFx compilation errors.

Comment: I'm first targeting iOS, when it works I will try Android.

Comment: I have ControlsFX 9 working on iOS (with Gluon VM). You need to compile it from the sources though. See this [link](http://docs.gluonhq.com/gluonvm/#_compilation_fails_when_casting_jdynamicinvokeexpr_to_instanceinvokeexpr) and add the option to the root `build.gradle` file (`compileJava` -> `options.compilerArgs` -> `"-XDstringConcat=inline"`). Then run `./gradlew clean install`, and then use it in your project (adding `mavenLocal()` and `compile 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:9.0.1-SNAPSHOT').

Comment: Hi Jose, I can confirm you that after compiling controlsfx as you said (need to also update gradle-wrapper.properties to 4.7 to support Java 9.0.4). I could launch the app, to see how GluonVM crashes as soon as it tries to use Jackson. Seems related with gvmMissing JVM_GetMethodParameters but I'm not an expert on this framework. I used this feature to avoid boilerplate, on this case annotations on DTOs but if is not going to be supported I should probably rethink about it.

Comment: I'm guessing the error is related with the usage of this module: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names

Comment: Gluon VM is still under development and some features are not supported yet, but they will be included at some point. You can file an issue [here](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues), and you can add a stacktrace and how to reproduce it.

Comment: I was going to file a issue when suddenly I can't even compile anymore, this happens all of the time when testing with GluonVM during last couple of weeks but now I can't even compile a clean sample app: https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues/54 Mobile projects with the old VM compile without this issue.

Comment: Use 2.0.20, and clean the project, including removing the .gradle folder of the project. If still that doesn’t work you can can also remove the ~/.gvm folder so the next run will start fresh.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jose, I learned quite a bit with you this couple of weeks. Deleting  ~/.gvm solved the issue. Missing functionality issue: https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues/55

Comment: I also updated https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues/54 with the workaround you mention. But I suppose you can close the issue if is not something fixable by the tooling.

Comment: I substituted the use of JVM_GetMethodParameters  for java.beans.ConstructorProperties for Jackson and serialisation/deserialisation stared working :) I documented this on the ticket.

Comment: @JoséPereda , Just a quick big thanks, I got my app fully working on the iPad emulator already, it would have been not possible without your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is quite a workaround that requires a bit of work. 
Fixes Jackson 2.9.5 to work in gluon jfxmobile-plugin 1.3.10.

1. To fix jackson-databind to be able build immutable objects with a single constructor.

1.1 Drop the usage of the JDK8 module parameter-names since this requires a non implemented VM feature.
Use instead java.beans.ConstructorProperties.

1.2 Jackson uses for ConstructorProperties support some Interfaces from JDK8 that can be safety included as part of your project.

```
java.beans.ConstructorProperties
java.beans.Transient
```

1.3 Force link JDK7 support

```
forceLinkClasses = [
    'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl',
]
```

2. To fix jackson-datatype-jsr310.

2.1 It uses some JDK8 interfaces that can be safety included in your project.

```
java.util.function.ToIntFunction
java.util.function.ToLongFunction
```

2.2 It uses some JDK8 methods that can be safety substituted by JDK6-7 implementations, simply include in your project the java files and look up the pre-JDK8 back ports of the Time API.

```
JavaTimeModule.java
SerializerToPach.java
```

3.3 Point your own JavaTimeModule to your own serializer.
3.4 Register in your ObjectMapper your own JavaTimeModule.

Voila, now you can use the lattest Jackson to create immutable objects and use JDK8 Time classes in gluon jfxmobile-plugin 1.x